# Change button position related to its center on mousemove

Tags: javascript

I want to create a button that when the user hovers on it the button will come a little closer to the cursor. I want the button to change its position related to its center, now it changes related to its upper left corner (0,0). Check my code to see what i mean. I am going to reuse this effect at every btn on my page.

Thanks in advance!!

```js
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

btn.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  btn.style.transform = `translate3d(+${e.offsetX / 10}px, +${e.offsetY / 10}px, 0px)`;

});

btn.addEventListener("mouseout", (e) => {
  btn.style.transform = "none";
});
```

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  display: inline-block;
  &:hover {
    // transform: translate(+10px, +10px);
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Contact us</a>
```

Comment: use `transform-origin: center`. For details of this property, see: [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: I have added it previously on my css file but nothing changed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to calculate the mouse offset relative to the center of the button. The center coordinate can be calculated from the return value of `getBoundingClientRect()`.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

btn.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  const { width, height } = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect()
  btn.style.transform = `translate3d(${(e.offsetX - (width / 2)) / 10}px, ${(e.offsetY - (height / 2)) / 10}px, 0px)`;

});

btn.addEventListener("mouseout", (e) => {
  btn.style.transform = "none";
});
```

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  display: inline-block;
  &:hover {
    // transform: translate(+10px, +10px);
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Contact us</a>
```